# parallel Reactor POCO C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, poco-libraries, reactor

I have designed a reactor server using POCO c++ libraries for practicing purposes.My reactor server is currently working fine .
Now i want to design the parallel reactor server. Here is the main function of my parallel reactor server :

```
1.unsigned short port = 8080;
2.ServerSocket ServerSocket(port);
3.Timespan timeout(3000);
4.ParallelSocketReactor reactor;
5.ParallelSocketAcceptor<MyHandler> acceptor(ServerSocket, reactor);
6.reactor.run();
```

Here MyHandler is the class where i have described all the handlers and member functions .
Now i am getting some errors while compiling my server :
line 4, argument list for class template "POCO::net::parallelSocketreactor" is missing.
And I have come across that run() is not a member of "POCO::net::parallelSocketAcceptor".

I have tried some techniques but didn't able to compile it! It will be very helpful if you guys provide me some solution regarding this parallel reactor.

Answer (score 0):

ParallelSocketReactor is a template class and ParallelSocketAcceptor has no `run()` member function, because it does not need it. Look [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.8/Net/testsuite/src/SocketReactorTest.cpp#L355) how to do it.